# What is the proper way to start a local PHP server, in PHP?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to make unit tests of a web crawling library with PHPUnit.

To do so, I need to set up a **temporary** web server in local to test properly.

I can do this:

```
exec('php -S 127.0.0.1:8888');
```

This looks ugly. And how can I even stop it?

So, is there a good way to start a temporary local web server (just for some tests) and then stop it? Knowing that, I want to do it in PHP, so I can just roll the tests out in every environment without worrying about launching a temporary server by hand every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what Symfony does with its [server:run](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html) command ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerStartCommand.php)).

Comment: For thoses who are interested, Symfony uses PCNTL which is one of the multiple [process extensions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php). I’ll definitely find my answer here.